# AttributeError at /cart/product-1 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, django

I am getting the above error trying to add a selected item to a cart and remove it if its already in cart. Below is my code. Any idea what am missing, thanks.

Cart Model:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, null=True, blank=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Card Id: %s" %(self.id)
```

item model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    sale_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

The View:

```
def UpdateCart(request, slug):
    cart = Cart.objects.all()
    try:
        item = Item.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except Item.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    except:
        pass
    if not item in cart.items.all():
        cart.items.add(item)
    else:
        cart.items.remove(item)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call cart = Cart.objects.all() the return is a queryset, that makes so that the variable cart does not have the attribute items, hence the error code when you try to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `cart` is returning a `Queryset` not a single row, you need to iterate over the `queryset` to make your code work.

```
carts = Cart.objects.all()

for cart in carts:
    if not item in cart.items.all():
        cart.items.add(item)
    else:
        cart.items.remove(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

This `cart = Cart.objects.all()` return the QuerySet object that doesn't have attribute for your many-to-many field. You should instead specify the exact record from the query set to access related items.

For now it looks like you are trying to add items to all the carts you have in DB:

```
cart.items.add(item)
```

Where, I guess, you actually wanted to add items to a specific cart like this (example, not a working code):

```
cart = Cart.objects.filter(by_some_field=value).latest()
```